# AttributeConverter vs UserType for Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I need to convert between a Map and a JSON string when communicating between a Java application and MySql. I've come across two very promising solutions: AttributeConverter and UserType.

Is there any pros/cons between choosing one solution over another? With all things considered equal, AttributeConverter sure does seem a lot simpler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AttributeConverter` requires JPA 2.1 (Hibernate 4.3+), but if it's available, it's a much cleaner choice. A custom UserType may break with future versions of Hibernate, while an AttributeConverter likely won't.

Make sure that you specify the `@Convert` annotation on the specific fields that you want to convert, rather than setting `autoApply`, since you don't want to convert all Maps or all Strings.

Also make sure that you use a library for the Map-String conversion, rather than hand-coding it.

Comment: For those who are not clear what library to use, Jackson is pretty simple in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as comparing these approaches goes, most of the time, `AttributeConverter`s are generalley a cleaner solution.

Othe than the JPA version difference, there is another big downside/difference that deserves noticing: **`@Convert` and `@Id` attributes don't work together** (you'll get deserialization errors). If you need such functionality, you'll have to resort to `UserType`s.